# Не найден указанный модуль

Tags: python, pyside, pyside2

При создании программы изначально использовался PyQT5, но в связи с некоторыми обстоятельствами пришлось использовать PySide2. При работе на одном компьютере всё проходило успешно, программа запускалась и собиралась в один exe. Этот файл не запускался на других компьютерах, а консоль говорила о том, что не находятся некоторые модули.
При переносе кода, модулей и так далее на другой компьютер, и при запуске main.py я получаю следующие ошибки, хотя сам PySide2 и прочее в настройках проекта присутствуют:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Администратор/Documents/PO/app/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui, QtWebEngineWidgets

  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\PySide2\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    _setupQtDirectories()

  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\PySide2\__init__.py", line 21, in _setupQtDirectories
    import shiboken2

  File "C:\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\shiboken2\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>

    from .shiboken2 import *
    ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль.
```

Каким образом мне можно помочь найти ему эти модули?

Comment: `хотя сам PySide2 и прочее в настройках проекта присутствуют`, в каких настройках? Использовали ли Вы venv? И было бы неплохо добавить в вопрос команду запуска c указанием директории запуска и выхлоп `echo %PATH%`

Answer (score 1):

На пк на котором все запускалось

> При работе на одном компьютере всё проходило успешно, программа запускалась и собиралась в один exe

выполните команду:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

скопируйте этот текстовый файл на другой пк на котором не получилось запустить

> не запускался на других компьютерах

затем выполните на этом же пк эту команду:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

и все ваши зависимости установятся как в рабочем проекте